# Собрать json массив из postmeta

Tags: wordpress

При создании записи я создал доп поля дат, ссылки и заголовка, которые назвал `event_start`, `event_date`, `event_titile`, `event_url`

Нужно собрать json массив следующего вида (значение `event_start` перенести в значение ключа `start` и так смежно с остальными):

```
{
  "start" : "20231113",
  "end" : "20231113",
  "title": "Заголовок",
  "url": "ссылка"
},
{
  ...
}
```

Массив будет передаваться в календарь событий, которой и читает json.

Comment: Не надо плодить дубли. Нужно задачу описать, а не придуманный путь её решения.

Comment: Сейчас задача описана? Еще есть, чего не хватает для понимания сути вопроса?

Comment: Ну например: `json_encode(['start' => get_post_meta($post_id, 'event_start', true), 'end' => get_post_meta($post_id, 'event_end, true), 'title' => get_post_meta($post_id, 'event_title, true), 'url' => get_post_meta($post_id, 'event_url, true)]);`

Comment: @Simon ага, а как это сделать со всеми записями, где `post_type` имеет значение `calendar_event`. То есть все записи где `post_type` равняется `calendar_event` занести в json массив

Comment: Перебрать записи циклом? Собственно, какой вопрос, такой и ответ. Но вообще получение всех записей, это неслишком хорошо, представьте что у Вас их будут сотни или тысячи.

Comment: Не подскажите, как лучше поступить, если мне массив нужен для передачи в плагин календаря событий. Плагин Fullcalendar, он принимает как раз json массив

Comment: Это может зависеть от множества факторов, к тому же все это по-хорошему должно быть ajax based таким образом и выборку имеет смысл делать на основе временного периода и тп. В таком случае и хранение этих данных в postmeta и выборка на основе мета значений, может быть не самым производительным.

Comment: Теперь немного лучше - ты *частично* описал что сделал, но не рассказал про ЦЕЛЬ (задачу). "собрать json массив" - это не задача, а промежуточное решение (и не факт что хорошее). Цель - это что-то типа "вывести  данные XXX из ПП в соответствии с логикой YYY".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 foreach ($arrayEventId as $value) {

        $item = array(
            'start' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime(get_post_meta($value, 'event_start', true))),
            'end' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime(get_post_meta($value, 'event_end', true))),
            'url' => get_post_meta($value, 'event_title', true),
            'title' => get_post_meta($value, 'event_url', true)
        );

        array_push($event_metadate, $item);
    }
    return $events = json_encode($event_metadate);
```

Решил проблему, а именно создан json массив со всеми нужными записями (фильтровал по post_type, но тут не имеет значения)

Было решение в комментариях сразу в json гнать, у меня не получалось вывести через echo (ошибка была что-то с массивом и строкой было связано), по этому я итоговый массив привел в json

В start и end мне нужно было передавать дату, по этому я прямо там и изменил их `date('Y-m-d', strtotime(get_post_meta($value, 'event_start', true)))`

Но спасибо за ответы, навели на решение. Да, может оно не идеальное, я новичек.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]